# writing basic queries for appengine's datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-datastore

I have been looking around for some simple plain examples that demonstrate :

```
submitting data to datastore
retrieving data from datastore
updating data in the datastore
deleting data from the datastore
```

Are there some good tutorials with java that demonstrate this or may be any one can explain/demonstrate it here ?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation has pretty much everything you need to get started.
The exact page you will need is [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) one.

Answer (score 1):

Use Objectify:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Basic_Operations:_Get,_Put,_Delete